# Displaying Calendar in an Android App

Tags: android, calendar

I would be obliged if someone could provide me a solution as to which component to be used so that I can display a fairly good looking calendar in my Android application.

I kept browsing for a solution for the past two days, but unfortunately could not find a solution. Since this is a very basic requisite, I am sure that there will be a perfect solution for this.

Please help with suggestions, comments and solutions.

Any help in this regard is well appreciated.

Looking forward,
Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do this is to develop your own calendar widget from scratch

Comment: ya i agree with the Jonney, As of now, We Android People has to developed our own Calendar widget from the scratch, what a hell

Answer (score 3):

I am also searching for this. For now, the only thing available seems to be this:
http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/

However it lacks swipe gestures, does not work on landscape, or higher density screens.

Answer (score 2):

Your question may be from 2010, however it still shows up on my first result page while googling the same question.

Therefore, I felt like I should share the 2 library I eventually selected that doesn't seem to be depreciated yet :

[Caldroid from Thomas Dao](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) and [Times Square from Jake Wharton](https://github.com/square/android-times-square).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a gridView for the month view, a list view for the agenda view and the scroll view for the day view. You could also use a gridView for the week view. For the grid, you could set the col # to 7 so that you get 7 columns for 7 days and have another child gridView to display the weekdays as headers. For the day, you could add a framelayout inside the scroll view. this would ensure that you can overlap and add multiple events to s single column. for the agenda view it would be simple to just use a list view and set list items using a list adapter.