# show calendar in android

Tags: android, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying Calendar in an Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763354/displaying-calendar-in-an-android-app)

Hi

i want to show a calendar application.It is the one application.And also i want to show a weekly calendar that is in this it show only days like sunday,monday,tuesday.....

So please tell me how to show a calender application and  weekly calender also.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Android has an inbuilt calender application..

If you need to access here is some [example](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm).

Comment: That's why you must add snippets from the link to your answer, bow your answer is useless as we open the link and finding nothing.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=Calendar&t=0